# Remote Desktop Connection to Laptop connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I've been using the following setup for a while now.

1. Logon to my desktop
2. remote onto my work laptop (also here at home and on the same network as the desktop)
3. connect the work laptop to work VPN
4. Get Work Done

Today the above stopped working and I can't find what changed.
I can remote into the laptop but if I then connect to VPN it kicks the desktop off the remote connection to the laptop. And while the laptop is connected to VPN I'm unable to ping desktop from laptop or laptop from desktop. As soon as I disconnect the VPN they are able to ping each other adn I can RDP in. any help appreciated.

Desktop = windows 11 Pro
Laptop = windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: what vpn client are you using

Comment: check `ipconfig /all` and `route print` on your laptop

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue
I was able to get my setup working again by changing the computer name when connecting via RDP.

for example, if you are connecting to computer named PC_A then instead enter that you are connecting to PC_A.local.
you can even try that with ping should work.